# What is causing my app to crash on button press?

Tags: android

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.rufflez.pagertabstriplistview.pagertabstriplistview" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.rufflez.pagertabstriplistview.pagertabstriplistview.FirstScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Base">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

On the Launch screen (FirstScreen):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/img_logo"
    android:src="@drawable/logo2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/img_title"
    android:layout_centerVertical="false"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/desc"
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="375dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn_start"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/start"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

My FirstScreen.java:

```
package com.rufflez.pagertabstriplistview.pagertabstriplistview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


public class FirstScreen extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first_screen);
    setupMessageButton();

}
private void setupMessageButton() {
    //1. Get reference to button
    ImageButton messageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);

    //2. Set the click listener to run code.
    messageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("DemoButtonApp", "Clicked Begin");
            startActivity(new Intent(FirstScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });
}

}
```

When I tap the `ImageButton` (`btn_start`) It crashes and says "Unfortunately, Video Game Historium has stopped" It doesn't seem to want to load the next screen. I looked in Logcat (which keeps going and going and never stopping) it's spitting out a few red errors:

```
EnterpriseContainerManager﹕ ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
E/SMD﹕ DCD ON  
CameraController﹕ handleMessage signal: 0  
CameraController﹕ handleMessage(0) before let go!{ when=-506ms what=0 target=com.sec.android.smartface.CameraController$EventHandler }
```

just to name a few. Any ideas? It was working until I took the screen from one project and imported it into this one. I imported the xml, java and drawables.

Edit: Added Crash Report:

```
11-18 10:04:47.683    9690-9690/com.rufflez.pagertabstriplistview.pagertabstriplistview
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.rufflez.pagertabstriplistview.pagertabstriplistview, PID: 9690
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.rufflez.pagertabstriplistview.pagertabstriplistview/com.rufflez.pagertabstriplistview.pagertabstriplistview.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
```

Comment: It's impossible to do anything but guess without your java code and logcat. You can filter by "error" then it won't be so long

Comment: `MainActivity` is not declared in your `manifest.xml`

Comment: possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998856/what-is-causing-my-app-to-crash-on-button-press/26998950?noredirect=1#comment42528518_26998950

Comment: by changing 
android:name="com.rufflez.pagertabstriplistview.pagertabstriplistview.FirstScreen" to 
android:name="com.rufflez.pagertabstriplistview.pagertabstriplistview.MainActivity" that just changes what the first activity to load is.

Comment: No, you need to add it in another `<activity>` tag

Comment: I added another <activity> and it still crashes when I tap the button

Comment: Ok, can't help anymore until you post the full stack trace from the crash

Comment: 9690-690/com.rufflez.pagertabstriplistview.pagertabstriplistview E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.rufflez.pagertabstriplistview.pagertabstriplistview, PID: 9690
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rufflez.pagertabstriplistview.pagertabstriplistview/com.rufflez.pagertabstriplistview.pagertabstriplistview.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: Oh no, please edit the post with the stacktrace. It is far easier to read there than in a comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65165/discussion-between-rob-hopper-and-codemagic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. 
Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme 
to use a Toolbar instead
```

This is the important part here. So, check your `themes.xml` and set `

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

Alternatively, you should be able to use as `parent`

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue. I had to change the order of my themes.xml around a little and add

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```